# Where are nodes processing packets in the c++ code of ns2?

Tags: c++, ip, ns2

I would like to create a function that enables a node to modify the `IP header` of incoming packets.

However, I can not find where to implement this function. I can not find in the `C++` code of `ns2` where nodes are processing packets. Does someone know?

My function writes the `IP address` of the node processing the packet into some fields of the packet header.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it: I added my function into the Classifier class and it's working, I can put information into the packet header.

I am now searching how to access the ID of the node which processed the packet, in order to write it into some fields of the IP header.

Answer (score 0):

simple way is to work in  routing protocol c++ code
(in forward function)
where you can extract packet header and make your changes

use this to access packet header

```
struct hdr_ip*  ih = HDR_IP(p);
```

Destination address :

```
ih->daddr()
```

Source address:

```
ih->saddr()
```

note: in ns2 you can't find formal IP address(class A,B,C,D).

regards